# Cross posting information across pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

The way I set my code won't let me obtain information from the previous page.

information on page 1:

```
public string Name{  get { return FirstName.Text; } private set{} }

public string Email { get { return email.Text; } private set { } }
```

information on page two (to obtain):

Mark up code:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Registration.aspx" %>
```

c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = "";
    string email = "";
    if (PreviousPage != null)
    {
        name = PreviousPage.Name;
        email = PreviousPage.Email;// both fields are always null... why?
    }
```

I changed my last section to this: still wont work

```
            Response.Redirect("CheckYourEmail.aspx");
    }
    ViewState["LoginName"] = FirstName.Text;
    ViewState["Email"] = email.Text;
    ViewState["Password"] = password1.Text;

}

public string Name { get { return ViewState["LoginName"].ToString() ; } private set { } }

public string Email { get { return ViewState["Email"].ToString(); } private set { } }

public string UserPassword { get { return ViewState["Password"].ToString(); } private set { } }
```

i also tried with Request["Email"];

wont work

Comment: Are you using `Server.Transfer()` to transfer execution to the second page?

Comment: its better if you learn more about the state-less nature of web and limitations of asp.net web forms abstraction to use it as stateful. otherwise you will run in to similar problems like this one

Comment: so i need to use stateview?!?

Comment: Adding and retrieiving from the viewstate dictionary isn't the solution you are looking for.  Are you initiating the cross page postback with a control taht implements the IButtonControl interface?  Like a Button control using the PostBackUrl Property?

Comment: it worked with postbackurl property instead of Response.Redirect..but why??!?!?

Comment: Response.Redirect() does not post any data to the server.  Working with Http can be confusing if you come from a desktop development background.  From the moment that asp.net serves up a page the page is dead on the server and destroyed.  It uses state information to recreate the previous state of the page if it is neeeded again.  This is accomplished with ViewState, Posted Values, SessionState, ApplicationState,  Cookies, an QueryString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see your code looks correct.  Do you have viewstate enabled for the textboxes?

When you do a cross page postback the lifecycle of the source page starts over again.  As soon as the target page accesses the PreviousPage Property.

Can you get the values through the Request object?

Request["FirsName"]

Comment: i enabled viewstate..and made the correction... i think i cant transfer info with view state across pages!!.. i updated my question

Comment: You are correct that you cant transfer viewstate between pages.  The point was that when you post to the target page the source page is lost, but when you access the PreviousPage property in the target page the source page restarts its page lifecycle.  How are you posting to the target page from the source page?

Comment: Its pretty obvious what your problem is now.  Your original code was fine.  The problem is that you aren't arriving at the target page with a postback.  You are NOT posting any values to the server.  Response.Redirect() is treated as a fresh view of a page as if you  were to just arrive at that page by clicking a link from any other page.  If you want to do a cross page postback you need to use a Button control and set the PostBackUrl property and not use Response.Redirect()

Answer (score 2):

Save the values in the session object and get these values from the other page.

```
// When retrieving an object from session state, cast it to 
// the appropriate type.
ArrayList customers = (ArrayList)Session["Customers"];

// Saving into Session to be retrieved later.
Session["Customers"] = customers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Http protocol is an state Less Protocol.
Try to use Session or cache to persist data.

Answer (score 0):

The previous page's instance is simply gone, so there's no way to retrieve data from it...